# Partial application of Printf.ksprintf

Tags: printf, ocaml, currying

I'm trying to write a version of `Printf.printf` that always appends a newline character after writing its formatted output.  My first attempt was

```ml
# let say fmt = Printf.ksprintf print_endline fmt;;
val say : ('a, unit, string, unit) format4 -> 'a = <fun>
```

The type signature looks right and `say` works as expected. I noticed that `fmt` is listed twice, and thought that partial application could eliminate it.  So I tried this instead:

```ml
# let say = Printf.ksprintf print_endline;;
val say : ('_weak1, unit, string, unit) format4 -> '_weak1 = <fun>
```

The function definition looks cleaner, but the type signature looks wrong and `say` no longer works as expected.  For example, `say` doesn't type check if the format string needs a variable number of arguments: I get an error that `say` "is applied to too many arguments".

I can use the `let say fmt = …` implementation, but why doesn't partial application work?

Answer (score 3):

OCaml's type-checker [loses polymorphism during partial application](https://ocaml.org/learn/faq.html#A-function-obtained-through-partial-application-is-not-polymorphic-enough).  That is, when you partially apply a function, the resulting function is no longer polymorphic.  That's why you see `'_weak1` in the second type signature.

When you include the `fmt` argument, you help the type-checker recognize that polymorphism is still present.

This process is called "eta conversion." Removing your `fmt` argument is "eta reduction" and adding it back in is called "eta expansion." You may encounter that terminology when working with other functional programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

This is the value restriction at work: https://ocaml.org/manual/polymorphism.html#s:weak-polymorphism . In brief, only syntactic values can be safely generalized in let-binding in presence of mutable variables in the language.
In particular,

```
let f = fun x -> g y x
```

is a syntactic value that can be generalized, whereas

```
let f = g y
```

is a computation that cannot (always) be generalized.

A example works quite well to illustrate the issue, consider:

```ml
let fake_pair x =
  let store = ref None in
   fun y ->
     match !store with
     | None -> 
       store := Some y;
       x, y
     | Some s ->
       x, s
```

then the type of `fake_pair` is `'a -> 'b -> 'a * 'b`.
However, once partially applied

```
let p = fake_pair 0
```

we have initialized the store mutable value, and it is important that all subsequent call to `p` share the same type (because they must match the stored value). Thus the type of p is `'_weak1 -> int * '_weak1` where `'_weak1` is a weak type variable, aka a temporary placeholder for a concrete type.